# To where does using std::cout; import visibility of cout?

Tags: c++, namespaces

In C++, when I declare an own namespace in a `.h` file like so:

```
namespace my_own {
    //...
}
```

Then does it make a difference if I declare a `using std::cout;` inside or outside of the namespace `my_own`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The namespace defines a scope. A `using` declaration respects scope, so if your `using std::cout;` is inside that scope, it only affects how parsing is done inside that scope.

If it's outside that scope, it affects parsing inside of whatever scope it's in (which will be everything in a file, if it's outside anything that defines a smaller scope).